# Trying to add multiple views but get a blank screen

Tags: java, android

I created a custom xml file with a LinearLayout and TextView. I have a for loop that i want go through an ArrayList and add the view to a ScrollView for each object. Below is the code i tried to achieve this, but it just gives me a blank screen. I tried to see if the ArrayList was empty, but that's not it. I didn't really know what i was doing when i tried this. I just wanted to see if it worked, but it didn't so what's the problem?

```
        for(int x = 0; x < runs.size(); x++){

        inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.run_layout, (ViewGroup) getCurrentFocus());

        TextView name = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvRunName);
        name.setText(runs.get(x).getName());

        llRuns.addView(layout);
    }
```

Heres the run_layout xml....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/run_background" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvRunName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```

Here's the Activities xml....

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".YourRuns"
android:background="#181818"
android:id="@+id/llYourRunsLayout">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/svRuns"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llRuns"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Post your xml as well. Also, did you consider using a `ListView`? They have various advantages when having a list of similar views.

Comment: The xml that i'm trying to add to the ScrollView or the Activities xml?

Comment: Do you have a reason for not using a [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)? As for me the layouts look like you don't need anything different; and using a `ListView` makes a more responsive UI.

Comment: Why are you using `(ViewGroup) getCurrentFocus()` as root node for the inflater; not sure if it can work, but I assume you wish to use `null` there?

Comment: This is not the complete code. You might have forgotten to call `setContentView()` or a number of other stuff. Are you sure your elements in `runs` contain non-empty texts?

Comment: @Bondax has a good point - if the screen is blank, you may not have setContentView(). Another thing you should do is add some text to the TextView, since TextView with empty strings will indeed appear as blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change (ViewGroup) getCurrentFocus() to null, becouse inflater.inflate() second parameter is parent of view, and when you start your activity for default no elements with focus. And you indicate two parents for view first on inflate, second when you say to add layout into llRuns.

```
for(int x = 0; x < runs.size(); x++){

    inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.run_layout, (ViewGroup) getCurrentFocus());

    TextView name = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvRunName);
    name.setText(runs.get(x).getName());

    llRuns.addView(layout);
}
```